# Assigning array property is always going to crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, xcode6, xcode6gm

I cannot understand why following code every time crashes on Xcode 6 GM using Swift. Could you help me to understand this issue?

Thank you in advance.

**OptionsToSelect.swift**

```
import Foundation

struct OptionToSelect {
    var value : Any
    var desc : String
    var available : Bool
}
```

**SomeClass.swift**

```
import Foundation

class SomeClass {
    var items = Array<OptionToSelect>()
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var c = SomeClass()
        c.items = [ /// <------------- __ EXC_BAD_ACCESS here, why?! __
            OptionToSelect(value: 1, desc: "A", available: true),
            OptionToSelect(value: 2, desc: "B", available: true)
        ]
    }
```

**Edit 1**
On twitter I got answer that it's related to `Any`, and indeed. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler still has various problems with `Any`, so the short answer is "bug in Swift." It also has trouble if `value` is a protocol. I suspect that it has trouble figuring out how to make a copy; but that's a guess.

But you should strongly avoid using `Any` here. You almost never should use `Any`. In most cases, you want a generic:

```
struct OptionToSelect<T> {
  let value : T
  let desc : String
  let available : Bool
}
```

(The way you're using it, `let` seems more appropriate than `var` here; do you really need to change these values?)

This does require that the entire array have the same kinds of values:

```
var items = [OptionToSelect<Int>]()
```

But that's usually correct anyway. If it isn't; if you need a mix of values, then you should consider what protocol all the values might conform to. That won't actually solve your problem (Swift will crash on a protocol here too), but the design will be much better than `Any`. If the best you can say about the type is "well, it's something," you're going to get a lot of complicated (and sometimes dangerous) down-casting code. You'll fight it every time you turn around.

To use a protocol here (or `Any`) you can either make `OptionToSelect` a class (which is the easiest answer), or hide the problem in a box:

```
struct OptionToSelect {
  let value : AnyBox
  let desc : String
  let available : Bool
}

final class AnyBox {
  let value: Any
  init (_ value: Any) { self.value = value }
}

[
  OptionToSelect(value: AnyBox(1), desc: "A", available: true),
  OptionToSelect(value: AnyBox(2), desc: "B", available: true)
]
```

(The same technique is needed for protocol types.)

Comment: I think this is a sub-bug of bug #46 here: https://github.com/practicalswift/swift-compiler-crashes - a (much worse than this) workaround is to define `OptionToSelect` as a class.

Comment: I don't know if turning `OptionToSelect` into a class is so bad. It makes me *feel* bad, but Swift seems to constantly nudge you away from structs to classes no matter how much we fight it :D This particular case seems exactly what structs are built to handle, and once again structs have this or that little problem that blows us up. I seem to bump into that a lot. (I do *want* them to work; I just don't know if they really do yet.)

Comment: BTW, #46 isn't crashing for me in 6.1.

Comment: Hey, well that's progress!